# Copy symbolic link and its target subdir to new dir

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync, symbolic-link, cp

I have a dir with a symbolic-linked subdirectory:

```
greg:/testA> ls 
foo -> alice
alice/
```

I need to copy the link "*foo-> alice*" (preserve it at destination) AND the subdirectory *alice/* to a new location *testB/*

The solution must not specify *alice* explicitly; it has to be obtained from the symlink.

I have tried and read everything, e.g. cp with its -H and -s switches, rsync with its -l, -K options and nothing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105368/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-g-dseas).